# Is there a list of which compiler supports which part of the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, standards, visual-c++-6

I'm just confused about c++'s standards right now,

I know there is three versions right now: c++98, c++03 and c++0x;

It is said that VC6 was wrote before C++ was standardized, so I don't mind if it does not support the standards, BUT, I found that vs2010 can't even support C++03, here is the code:

```
class A
{
    class B { };
    friend class X;
};

class X
{
    A::B mx;
    class Y : A::B
    {
        A::B my;// This should be wrong in C++98 and C++03
                // But it works in VS2010
    };
};
```

after the compile fails, I think maybe vs2010 supports c++0x, so I changed the code to:

```
class A
{
    class B { };
    friend class X;
};

class X : A::B // This should be right in c++0x, but it is an error in vs2010
{
    A::B mx;
    class Y : A::B
    {
        A::B my;
    };
};
```

So this made me very confused, and I'm here asking: which version of c++ standard is vs2010 supporting, if it does not totally supporting the standard, is there a list of which tells me which complier supports which standard?

Comment: "This should be right in c++0x, but it is an error in vs2010"  No it isn't.  If you add an `int main() { }` it compiles and links without error using Visual C++ 2010 SP1.  Clang and g++ also accept it.  Clang also accepts the first code snippet as well.

Comment: it did complie, but there is an error in the error list: IntelliSence: class "A::B" can not be accessed

Comment: The IntelliSense error checker does not catch all errors and reports some false positives (if you do find false positives in the IntelliSense error checking, please feel free to submit them as issues at [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com)).  From a conformance standpoint, all that really matters is whether the compiler compiles the code, which it does.  The IDE and the compiler use completely different frontends.

Comment: if you delete the code in class X, the complier will report an error, change change class X to this: class X : A::B{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're specifically interested in MS VC++ versions... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84h5b78.aspx - vary the version number in the "Other Versions" drop-down combobox to see the various releases.

Answer (score 1):

C++98 does not exist as a Standard anymore. It was superseded by C++03. Secondly, because of the way that C++11 coming out was timed, VS2010 supports a kind of half-way-house between C++03 and C++11.

More than that, every implementation has warts. Do you think that it doesn't support C++03 because it doesn't have `export`?

Comment: "C++98 does not exist as a Standard anymore" - the standard is pretty much still there. Do you mean it is no longer implemented by today's compilers?